# Dialogflow composite entity parameter is undefined when it shouldn't be

Tags: javascript, node.js, dialogflow-es

Long story short, I'm making a real estate agent chatbot and I just implemented a filter allowing the user to search within a range of numbers (e.g. at least one bedroom, under $2500). In order to do this, I made an entity_range composite entity composed of the range type (e.g. at most, exactly) and the entity itself (unit-currency for price, plus some custom entities like the number of bedrooms). Prior to creating entity_range, the entities themselves worked fine. But now, it seems as though the entity part of entity_range is undefined. See a sample of my code below:

```
function get_count(req, res) {
  console.log("price: " + req.queryResult.parameters["entity_range"]["unit-currency"])
  var price, beds, baths, num_filter_funct
  if(req.queryResult.parameters["entity_range"]["unit-currency"] != undefined) {
    price = req.queryResult.parameters["entity_range"]
    console.log("price: " + price)
  } else {
    console.log("could not find parameter")
  }
```

Before creating entity_range, my code looked exactly the same, except without ["entity_range"] between parameters and ["unit-currency"]. Anyway, this code logs:

```
price: undefined
could not find parameter
```

after the input "How many for $2500," with the following diagnostic info:

```
...
"queryResult": {
    "queryText": "how many for $2500",
    "parameters": {
      "entity_range": [
        {
          "unit-currency": {
            "amount": 2500,
            "currency": "USD"
          }
        }
      ]
    }...
```

So the entity "unit-currency" is recognized by Dialogflow, but not by my program. entity_range does allow users to not specify a range, so that's not the issue:
[see screenshot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XVm7M.png).

I would greatly appreciate any advice you have to offer!

Comment: Can you also add an image that shows the Parameters section of the Intent that uses `entity_range`? I can see why this is happening in code, but want to make sure I understand what in your Intent is causing this.

Answer (score 1):

That JSON shows entity_range being an array instead of an object. an object.

parameters.entity_range[0][“unit-currency”] should work.  Note the [0].  You’ll also want to add some checks before this to make sure enitiy_range exists and it’s length is > 0.

And this part is just a guess but perhaps you mistakenly clicked the “Is List” box for this parameter in dialogflow?  I’m checking it would probably make it be an object instead of an array and your existing code would work.